# 2006 Haundai Elantra stalled out of highway, fuel issue

Tags: fuel-system, hyundai, elantra

I have a 2006 Haundai Elantra.  About 3 months ago the check engine light came on and I thought it was to do with the oil needing to be serviced.  I went ahead and got that taken care of but the light did not go off. I meant to look into it but I figured no telling it’s an old car... and maybe the tech forgot to turn it off.  Then in a week or two after that I started having bad issues with filling my fuel tank.  It would burp back gasoline into the filler neck and be a royal pain to get a descent amount of gas in.  This morning I added gas, to just over half a tank from less than say 1/8 and drove about 20 miles highway to work.  Then when I went to drive home this afternoon it shuttered and stalled off at the stop light to get back on the highway.  I restarted the engine with minor difficulty and decided to try to limp it home and see what the problem is.

I probably got about 2 miles down the road when it started having issues again.  I got it safely off the road but wasn’t able to get it started again.  I know this issue is probably to do with the fuel system.  I have not had any other issues with power or starting, other than a dead battery (replaced with new), sense I started driving this car.  I’m fairly sure the fuel evap system is crapped out but I want to know what are my easiest and cheapest or at least most efficient bets to get the thing running long enough to get it home and take a good look that isn’t by a busy highway and not have to pay for a tow truck.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!